# NameError: name 'recPower' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a assignment and am encountering this error. NameError: name 'recPower' is not defined

1. Write a recursive function called pow(base, power) that takes in two numbers. First number is a base and the second number is a power. The function will return the number raised to the power. Thus, if the number is 2 and the power is 4, the function will return 16. (75 points).
2. Write a main() function that asks for a number and a power. Then calls the recursive function created in step 1 (15 points).
   DO NOT use the algorithm on page 432 of your book:

   def: recPower (a, n):

   ```
   if n == 0:
       return 1
   else:
       factor = recPower (a, n//2)
       if n%2 == 0:
            return factor * factor
        else:
             return  factor * factor * a
   ```

My current code is as follows

```
def main():
 a=input("enter base :")
 n=input("enter power :")

 print ("Total = ",recPower(a,n))

main()

def recPower (a,n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a*recPower(a,n-1)
```

`
The error I get when I run it is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".py", line 7, in 
    main()
  File ".py", line 5, in main
    print ("Total = ",recPower(a,n))
NameError: name 'recPower' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Functions are stored in identifiers. You have to define it first. Try this one:

```
def recPower(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a * recPower(a, n - 1)


def main():
    a = int(input("enter base :"))
    n = int(input("enter power :"))

    print ("Total = ", recPower(a, n))


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your 'run' function after 'recPower'.

As also mentioned you need to convert the strings that are returned from input() into integers or floats, using either int() or float(). When you try to operations like division you'll get TypeError exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

functions must be defined before any are used.

try this code

```
def recPower(a, n):
    # or just a, n = int(a), int(n) is fine
    if isinstance(a, str):
        a = int(a)
    if isinstance(n, str):
        n = int(n)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a * recPower(a, n - 1)


def main():
    a = input("enter base :")
    n = input("enter power :")

    print ("Total = ", recPower(a, n))


main()
```

Comment: I ran that code and now it gives me the following error: enter base :5
enter power :5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File ".py", line 12, in main
    print ("Total = ", recPower(a, n))
  File ".py", line 5, in recPower
    return a * recPower(a, n - 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Austin That error because of type casting. if your input is not always integer, try this `a = int(a)`. So I fixed my code

Answer (score 0):

write your method above the main code, because if you write at under the main code method is undefinied